# How I can make an Empty Array of View and then initialize it for render in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I got 3 coded Views, with this names: circleView1, circleView2, circleView3
Which basically render a circle Image of 1,2 and 3.

**My Goal: I want append those 3 Views to an Empty Array for usage.**

*The codes have issue, not working!*

```
import SwiftUI


struct circleView1: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "1.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }
struct circleView2: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "2.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }
struct circleView3: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "3.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }



struct ContentView: View {
    
   var shapeArray: [View] = [EmptyView()]
    

    var body: some View {
        
        

        VStack
        {
            shapeArray()
        }
        .onAppear()
        {
            shapeArray().append(circleView1)
            shapeArray().append(circleView2)
            shapeArray().append(circleView3)
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: A `View` is not a thing - it's a protocol that specifies what conforming types must support - so you can't have an array of something that's not a thing (at least not in the current version of Swift). You can have an array of `Image` views, or `AnyView` views, but not arbitrary types (which are all different) that conform to View. Why do you think you need an array here? And, in this question, all the "circle" views are actually the same underlying type. Why are they defined as different types?

Comment: It is not the way how SwiftUI works with views, and eventhough this is possible, by wrapping every in AnyView, but many automatic things will/might be broken (like environment/environmentObject, binding, equating, etc.) ... do you really want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SwiftUI's wrapper `AnyView` to erase the type. Even though it is technically possible, I wouldn't really recommend this kind of using and consuming Views.

My working example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct circleView1: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "1.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }
struct circleView2: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "2.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }
struct circleView3: View { var body: some View { Image(systemName: "3.circle").font(Font.largeTitle).padding() } }

struct ContentView: View {
   var shapeArray: [AnyView] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<self.shapeArray.count) { i in
                self.shapeArray[i]
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.shapeArray.append(AnyView(circleView1()))
        self.shapeArray.append(AnyView(circleView2()))
        self.shapeArray.append(AnyView(circleView3()))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```